# Getting row index from an ImageButton click in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, imagebutton

I have a Gridview with ImageButtons added to a column via a templatefield.  I've attached a function to the "OnClick" event.

Once in this function, how can I get the index of the row that has the button that has been clicked.  It appears that all I have is the mouse coordinates on the page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of looping through the rows you can use this

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="ibtn1" ... RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' 
OnClick="button_click"/>

...

protected void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ImageButton ibtn1 = sender as ImageButton;
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ibtn1.Attributes["RowIndex"]);

    //Use this rowIndex in your code
}
```

Comment: Sweet - this is more efficient - I'll integrate it.

Comment: Changing my answer to this, since this is closer to the solution I actually implemented.

I ended up setting the TabIndex value, and looked at that.  How do you use "RowIndex"? is that a custom attribute?

Answer (score 12):

Cast the sender to an ImageButton then cast the image button's NamingContainer to a row:

VB:

```
Dim btn as ImageButton = CType(sender, ImageButton)

Dim row as GridViewRow = CType(btn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
```

C#:

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;

GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
```

Answer (score 3):

Would agree with bdukes that the simplest option is to use the CommandArgument. Bind your data's unique ID number into that property, then handle the _RowCommand event.

For example:

```
<asp:TemplateField >
    <HeaderStyle Width="20" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="images/icons/iCal.png" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Event_ID") %>' ToolTip="iCal" runat="server" Height="18" Width="18" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


Protected Sub gv_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gv.RowCommand

   e.CommandArgument    'use this value in whatever way you like

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very good trick.
I have another trick also.
You can try it...

```
 protected void userGridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            GridViewRow rowSelect = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int rowindex = rowSelect.RowIndex;
         }
    }
```

It's a also good method.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I've found is to use the [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.command.aspx) event over the [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.click.aspx) event, and send the item ID as the command argument.

You could also loop over the rows in the GridView and compare the ImageButton in the row to the `sender` argument in your Click event.

Comment: I do this all the time with GridView bindings. It is great!

Comment: It works but it's absurd that RowCommand can't tell you what row fired the command.